# How to create interactive charts

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter, ipython

I want to create a chart using python where I could be able to see data related to different data points. For example I want to compare 5 different qualities (data points) of 10 different products.

Now is it possible to select these data points one at a time from a drop down list and show it's data for all 10 products?

Till now I have only created simple comparison charts using `matplotlib`.  Is `matplotlib` is capable of doing that? Any link or related documentation will be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

There are several ways of producing a dropdown field in matplotlib.

#### (a) Jupyter notebook

In order to get a dropdown field in a Jupyter notebook, you can use the `ipywidgets.interact()` command. I have already provided [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41667906/4124317) on how to use that.

[image]

#### (b) Matplotlib within PyQt.

You can embed matplotlib into PyQt and use the PyQt widgets to obtain a drop down field. [Here is a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41677416/4124317) for that.

[image]

#### (c) Matplotlib widgets

Matplotlib provides some interactive widgets out of the box. Unfortunately it does not provide a dropdown field. But if requirements are not too strict, one could use a slider to accomplish the effect of chosing different datasets. Find [an example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41152160/4124317).

[image]